# Copy full disk image from Android to computer

Tags: android, adb

I have a smartphone without the possibility to insert an SD-card.
I would like to make a dump of the biggest partition (cause I lost files and I'd like to use a dump to recover them).

The partition is 10GB.

I was looking for an `ADB` command to `pull` using `dd` but nothing...

I tried to use `Carliv touch recovery` with a 32GB USB key by OTG but the USB key didn't mount ... Then I couldn't use `dd` directly on the phone using `Aroma file manager` and a terminal emulation.

Thank you!

#### I don't understand why they closed a question that has already an accepted answer by linking a completely different question. Copying a file and copying a partition are 2 different things.

Comment: no need for `dd`. make sure that `adbd` is running as root and then just `adb pull` the block device file for your partition.

Comment: Wow, Thank you very much ! For those who look for : `adb pull /dev/block/mmcblk0 mmcblk0.img`

Comment: `/dev/block/mmcblk0` is a device file for the whole storage device. You probably wanted to pull just a single partition. Run `mount` command to find the device file for the partition you're looking to dump which would look something like `/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata` and `adb pull` that

Comment: please post the answer and mark it accordingly. It is possible to make a DD image, however not as easy. I missed the answer in this comment section because it's not marked.

Comment: I wrote the solution in comments. Thank you for your reply, don't know who down vote through...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As said in comment, `adb pull /dev/block/mmcblk0 mmcblk0.img` worked for me. A "DD image" is only a binary image file of the device.

Comment: Nice and simple. Although it gave me a "Permission denied" error, even with root and adbd Insecure, running the command in recovery mode (using TWRP) allowed the partition to be transferred without a hitch.

Comment: yes of course, the partition has to be `unmounted` then only in `recovery mode`.

Comment: @Alexis_FR_JP, I created a "dd image" as you mentioned, but when I had to use this to restore everything, my phone didn't want to boot up... 
Something went wrong with the "system" partition because when I re-flashed it, everything worked again... I started my phone in recovery mode (TWRP). In other hands, the transfer size when I backed up the data and when I restored was same and equaled than the physical size. So I have no idea why was not worked the restore...

Comment: I guess this way doesn't work anymore to restore a phone. I don't know exactly the reason. I guess due to more complicated boot path and some other security features and/or encrypted partition.
Usually there is a proper way for each smartphone.

Comment: ADB throws: 'remote object '/dev/block/mmcblk0' does not exist'

Comment: Well, the name of the device may change. You need to check which block device corresponds to the memory.

Comment: This method worked for me. I "pushed" the image on another device. The system booted fine, but all the data was gone. I guess this is because it was encrypted, and the encryption keys are device specific somehow. I didn't try a push on the same device.

Answer (score 22):

You want to copy a disk from your android device to your computer (preferably on your fastest drive) for faster and lossless analysis/recovery.

This is short step-by-step guide **in windows** (*linux: scroll down*) to achieve it using the linux tool `dd` intended for precise, bit-wise copies of data.  Credits go to scandium [on xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=2738944) for the code, [see his post for more details](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1818321).

**Prerequisites**

- make sure your device is **[rooted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_(Android))** and **[busybox](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/ru.meefik.busybox/)** is installed

**Windows**:

1. **install [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html)**. During install, add `netcat` (under Net) and `pv` (under `util-linux`) packages; the standard install is located in `C:\` so make sure you have enough disk space beforehand;
2. **install [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)** e.g. through Android Studio. Make sure to add `adb.exe` executable file to the *path variable* to access it properly ([guide](http://www.howtodroid.com/2014/02/how-to-add-adb-command-prompt-windows.html)).
3. Open two cygwin consoles/terminals (one sending data, one receiving data) and enter in one of the terminals to enter the device:

```bash
    # terminal 1
    adb forward tcp:5555 tcp:5555   # forward data over tcp connection
    adb shell                       # open a connection
    su                              # gain root access
    BUSYBOX=/system/xbin/busybox    # default location for most bb installers
    
    # note: adapt the variable `BUSYBOX` to point to your install directory
    #       the TWRP default is `BUSYBOX=/sbin/busybox` (in case of bricked device)
```

4. Decide what partition to copy, the `/dev/block/mmcblk0` partition is usually the one containing the data you typically would want.
5. In the following code, adapt the partition name according to 4. and *quickly* one after another type in `terminal 1` and `terminal 2`:

```bash
    # terminal 1
    $BUSYBOX nc -l -p 5555 -e $BUSYBOX dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0
```

```bash
    # terminal 2
    nc 127.0.0.1 5555 | pv -i 0.5 > $HOME/mmcblk0.raw
```

> This saves the partition in the cygwin home directory (in a nutshell: it sends/receives output of `dd` over a tcp connection)

**Look at the files / analysis**

- To mount the partition in Windows you can use **([OSFmount](http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html))**.
- To analyze the files I recommend **[Active@ Undelete](http://www.active-undelete.com/)** but there are tons of alternatives. With that program you can also directly load all partitions from the file (without mounting it, so step 5 is redundant in this case).

**Guide for GNU/Linux users**: install **`netcat`** and **`pv`** (step 1), use the **[Disks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Disks)** utility to analyze

Comment: Depending on ADB toolkit version *adb shell* command may not work. Especially when copying to Windows OS (adding extra CR to LF, etc.) The right command in such cases would be: *adb exec-out 'dd if=/dev/block...* In contrast to shell, exec-out deals binary data much better.

Comment: thanks! please feel free to edit and improve the answer =) I've never used exec-out

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the Disks utility. I was able to mount the `system` partition image with it, but `userdata` gives an error: **cannot mount /dev/loop0 read-only (udisks-error-quark, 0)** From a web search, "udisks-error-quark, 0" seems to be a generic error shown for all sorts of different problems.

Answer (score 12):

Run as root:

```
adb root
```

Use `dd` to output content into stdout and write file on your computer:

```bash
adb shell 'dd if=/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/XXXXXX 2>/dev/null' > XXXXXX.img
```

Or all (see `cat /proc/partitions`)

```bash
adb shell 'dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0 2>/dev/null' > mmcblk0.img
```

Comment: Please explain these command lines

Comment: This perfectly answered my question that requires the use of `dd`. But I haven't tried.

Comment: Depending on ADB toolkit version *adb shell* command may not work. Especially when copying to Windows OS (adding extra CR to LF, etc.)
The right command in such cases would be:
*adb exec-out 'dd if=/dev/block...*
In contrast to shell, exec-out deals binary data much better.

Comment: Use double quotation instead (single quotation gives "The system cannot find the path specified."), I've tested on win10.

Comment: I was getting `adbd cannot run as root in production builds` when trying to run `adb root`. Instead, I was able to switch to root as part of the shell command: `adb shell "su -c 'dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0'"` (per this answer: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/resolve-adbd-cannot-run-as-root-in-production-builds.4560483/#post-88274507)